# Add PLAIN to the list of accepted SASL mechanisms of Apache Qpid Broker-J

Tags: qpid, sasl

I'm trying to connect to a locally running instance of Apache Qpid Broker-J using AMQP.Net Lite, which supports only ANONYMOUS, PLAIN and EXTERNAL SASL mechanisms. The broker rejects connection requests as it demands one of the following mechanisms: CRAM-MD5, SCRAM-SHA-1, SCRAM-SHA-256. Is there a way to configure the broker to accept PLAIN? I cannot find it in the documentation.

Answer (score 6):

maybe I am too late, but why not save time others?

Initially the PLAIN SASL mechanism is blocked by the default value of "**secureOnlyMechanisms**" attribute of the authentication provider configuration. The default value is "PLAIN", but when set to "" (empty string), the PLAIN SASL mechanism is accepted even for non-SSL connections. Here's an excerpt of my "config.json"

```
  "authenticationproviders" : [ {
    "id" : "88d0c7eb-4a75-4e5e-85ff-19185e0394d7",
    "name" : "plain",
    "type" : "Plain",
    "secureOnlyMechanisms": "",
    "users" : [ {
      "id" : "4ebb8d66-f8e0-4efb-9bb9-c4578292ab43",
      "name" : "guest",
      "type" : "managed",
      "password" : "guest"
    } ]
  } ]
```